# Datatable filter wont work

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/fw8zu34t/

all I have is:

```
$('#admin_users_table').DataTable.column(3).data().filter(function(v) {
  alert ('!');
  return false;
}).draw();
```

so it should result an empty table but it returns the whole one. Alert'es run. Im using v2.1.4